# Mobile Toggle Menu - How to Push Content outside the view of the viewport?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I'm working on a mobile layout and came across the following question.

This is more of a "is there a commonly accepted term for what I'm describing" question.  In the hopes of finding tutorials / explanations regarding this method - is there a commonly accepted name for the following layout / toggle menu column scenario?

[image: Screenshot of my layout description]

Essentially once the toggle menu is shown the original content of the site is pushed to the right, partially out of the viewport, and the toggle menu is shown.

Does this method have a name?  I'm not sure how to describe this in order to find resources on best practices?  Also, does anyone have any ideas on what type of CSS / jQuery combo would be necessary in order to scroll/push the original content off of the viewport in this way?

Any information, commonly accepted terms, demos, or brief explanations are greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: There are different ways to do it, depending on the exact behavior you need : when the menu is opened, do you want a horizontal scroll or to keep your viewport at 100% ?

Comment: Great question - sorry I forgot to mention that I do not want a horizontal scrollbar.  I'd like for the viewport to stay at 100%, and for the primary way of seeing the main content again to be simply toggling the menu to be hidden again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So...

Assuming this (ugly) markup :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

The two last div are your menu and your content.

Then, the CSS :

```
*
{
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}

html, body
{
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

body > div
{
    width : 100%;
    max-width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
}

body > div > div
{
    width : 200%;
    height : 100%;
    -webkit-transform : translate(-40%);
    -webkit-transition : -webkit-transform 1s linear;
}

    body > div > div.hover
    {
         -webkit-transform : translate(0%);
    }

body > div > div > div
{
    float : left;
    height : 100%;
}

body > div > div > div:first-child
{
    width : 40%;
    background : red;
}
body > div > div > div:first-child+div
{
    width : 50%;
    background : blue;
}
```

It's quite simple (even if it may not seems simple) :

1. a first div at 100% and overflow:hidden. it prevent the scroll. The
   body should be used to do this, but an iOS oddity prevents this.
2. the second div is a larger container who will hold the two floated
   div. This larger container is translated.
3. the third divs are your menu and content, floated.

I calculated the % on the fly, you may have to tweak them.

Then, a bit your jquery to test it :

```
<script>
$(document).on('touchstart', function()
{
    $("body > div > div").addClass("hover");
});
</script>
```

You should not use the touchstart event, it's only for demo purposes.

Tested on iOS 5.1 and Android 2.3.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! You are a lifesaver. That helps tremendously to see the different technologies coming together in an example like that. I was a bit clueless prior to your answer on how to implement something like this on my own.  Now I just have to decide whether to use this custom solution or Pageslide plugin another user suggested.  Thanks mdi!

Comment: Just a precision : you may have to remove all the height : 100%, they are just for example purposes as the divs are empty.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I put together a demo from your example code and the 100% heights made things visibly "work" even without any content yet, great temporary example solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is of any use to you, but there is a jQuery plugin that does something similar to what you are describing.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

Comment: That is amazing!  Exactly what I was trying to describe - thank you so much!!